# IIS and Active Directory Permissions

Tags: asp.net, iis, active-directory

I have built an ASP.NET website for my companies intranet. It is utilizing windows authentication, we use active directory. What I want to do is restrict certain pages of this website (add, delete) so only a few people can access it. Any ideas on how to do this? I want to create groups in active directory so I can just add people to them and they automatically can access these restricted pages.

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to tell ASP.NET what to protect and how. This is done through your web.config settings. For example, if you change your web.config for your ASP.NET application to reflect the following:

```
<system.web>
     <authentication mode=“Windows“ /> = Windows AD Auth
     <identity impersonate=“true“/> 
     <authorization>
        <allow users=“*“/>  = Only allow authenticated users into the web site
        <deny users=“?“/>  = Deny unauthenticated users         
     </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Then add location config sections that only allow certain **roles** to visit certain parts of the application. Roles translate to Active Directory Groups, for instance:

```
<location path="Admin">
    <system.web>
      <authorization>
        <allow roles=“BUILTIN\Administrators“ /> = only allow users of this AD Group
        <deny users=“*“/> = Deny everyone else
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

This tells ASP.NET to only allow users within the Active Directory Group called "Administrators" to get access to the pages within that folder.

Also, the "path" setting of the location node in the web.config file can be set to individual files of your application if they are not separated out into a folder.

If your app is MVC, the location "path" variable corresponds to the path taken to invoke your endpoints. These are usually specified in your RouteConfig.cs file. For instance, if you have an MVC urls  "website.com/viewA/show" vs "website.com/AdminView/show".  To restrict access to viewA the path would be "viewA" and "AdminView" for restricting access to AdminView urls.

Comment: I did this, putting the first code under the configuration node and the second directly under the system.web node. It won't let anyone log onto it through the server now. But when I launch it directly from IIS, it works fine but allows me to view the page i'm trying to restrict, and i'm not in the group that i'm allowing. Any ideas? Also, all of my views are under one folder

Comment: If you app is MVC, the location "path" variable corresponds to the path taken to invoke your views. For instance "website.com/viewA/show" vs "website.com/AdminView/show".

Comment: Oh I see. So I try <location doctors/views/DoctorsList ="Delete.aspx">, the sites name is doctors, and the DoctorsList folder contains the delete page along with all the other views. But IIS gives me an error that says my configuration file is not well-formed xml

Comment: correct, that is malformed xml. try: <location path="views/DoctorsList/Delete.aspx" > ... </location> provided that "/views/DoctorsList/Delete.aspx" is an actual url in your application.

Comment: Oh I always thought that the "path" was the folder path. I entered in the actual URL path, and is not kicking an xml error. But for some reason when I turn impersonation on, it gives me the "NT authority\anonymous logon" error. It is connecting to SQL server, but this error does not occur when impersonation is off. And wither or not impersonation is on, it recognizes the user at the top of the screen.

Comment: Your SQL connection is using the current user's credentials. You can avoid that by specifying the credentials in the connection string, or turn impersonation off in that case.

Comment: I turned impersonation off, and it still allows me to access the delete page, though I am not in the group I allowed to access it. Is it a necessity to have impersonation on?

Comment: my bad, :-/ you need impersonation on. You will need to either give access to the users in the database, or change your SQL connection to not use impersonation. Your can learn more about impersonation in detail here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms998351.aspx

Comment: Ok, I got the connection string to work! I have impersonation on and passed credentials. Does the section of code specifing the location path security go at the top of web.config right under <configuration>? That's where I have mine and it doesn't seem to be doing anything.

Comment: Yeah that's exactly where I have mine =/ I have  <location path = "doctors/doctorslist.aspx">
<system.web>
<authorization>
<allow roles="BUILTIN\viewgroup"/>
<deny users="*"/>
</authorization>
</system.web>
</location>

Comment: yikes, try <deny users="?" /> to verify auth is kicking in, otherwise something else is wrong. :-/

Comment: Yeah it still works with that too. Maybe it has something to do with the folders? the path is C:\inetpub\wwwroot\doctors\Views\DoctorsList\delete and the delete page is what i'm trying to restrict. The web.config file is located right under doctors. It still doesn't work when my "path" is doctors/doctorslist/delete.aspx

Comment: perhaps I am confused with the ".aspx" part in your url. If your app is MVC and you are protecting certain actions in the controller, you would need to also add the [Authorize] attribute to your action function. Check out: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute.aspx

Comment: I had that in my controller file, but I looked into it and thought that the authorize attribute is only supposed to go along with forms authentication. The .aspx part is not in my URL, I just saw it on examples so I thought to try to put that there. I wouldn't be protecting a certain action, just the page. Do you think I should put the authorize attribute back in?

Comment: if the ".aspx" part is not actually in your url, then the location node is rendered invalid. The path element should be your exact url for accessing the page (minus the application path and leading backslash)

Comment: Should the .aspx be in my URL? I tried taking that part off and it still doesn't work. The URl that works is http://server:8080/doctors/doctorslist/Delete. The path in my web.config is doctors/doctorslist/Delete

Comment: If the web.config is located under "/doctors" directory then the appropriate path variable for the location node in that file would be <location path="doctorslist/Delete" > .. </>

Comment: That seems to be working better now, it asks for a username and password when I navigate to the delete page though. And when I hit log in it just shows the prompt again

Comment: Here is something I noticed- does the group have to be in the Builtin group? Instead of BuiltIn/Administrators, I would use company groups/IIS/Deletegroup correct? Or would I need to create a group within the Builtin section?

Answer (score 1):

You would use the file/folder permissions to restrict users to those pages. So if you have a folder called HR with some pages in it, you would set the folder permissions on the HR folder to allow Read access to the HR group in Active Directory.

Comment: I attempted to do this. The thing is I think people are authenticated through the group IIS_IUSR, and I can add people to this group but I can't specify what pages I want them to be able to access.

Comment: They shouldn't be authenticated through IIS_IUSR if you have identity impersonate=true in your web.config. Also, in IIS, click on the Authentication icon in your website properties and disable Anonymous authentication and enable Windows Authentication.

Comment: I have anonymous turned off. But when I set impersonate to true, the site won't work at all.

Comment: Can you check that your AD user account has permissions to the web root folder?

Comment: Yes, it does have permissions to view it. It's weird, the site will work when directly launched from IIS, but is not accessible anywhere else in the network.

Comment: When I try to log on, it asks me for my username and password (it shouldn't with windows authentication) and when I enter them in it says "NT authority\anonymous logon", but I got in just fine with impersonation off

Comment: Hum, that seems like the app might be trying to connect to a SQL server maybe, and because you are impersonating and the account doesn't have access to SQL it is giving you that error. Is that the case perhaps?

Comment: Yes, it is connecting to sql server. Sorry I would have mentioned that but I didn't think that was the problem. When I have impersonation set to off, it still recognized the user, it says "welcome domain/user!" at the top.

Comment: Yeah but I don't think you'll be able to restrict access to subfolders without impersonation set to true. So then the problem is SQL access. Either use SQL authentication and specify a SQL user/password in your connection string, or if using Windows auth, you'll need to give all domain users access to your database.

Comment: I  am passing credentials through the connection string and impersonation is set to on, but now it prompts the user to enter in a username and password. However, it also says hello user! at the top of the screen. Would it be necessary to give all users access to the data base if the credentials are already specified?

Comment: Maybe you can post your connection string? Just eek out the username and password.

Comment: I got the connection string to work now, I accidently had the user ID part wrong. It's successfully connecting to the DB now, I just need to get the location part working to limit people to view that page